# 0x80041feb Error in Visual Studio 2010 when try to add ResourceDictionary

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, hresult

When I try to add ResourceDictionary in any wpf project in Visual Studio 2010, it throw "Exception from HRESULT:0x80041feb" exception. 
How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.